# Detect different taps with jgesture and play soundfiles

Tags: jgestures

I'm trying to create some touch events for a cordova application/game, but the documentation on the jgestures site is not helping much.

For example: I have three different audio files and when I tap with one finger on the screen I want to play the first audio file and when I tap with two fingers I want to play the second audio file... and so on.

Help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

On touchend event of element, check for event.touches count and do the required operations.

```
element.on('touchend', function(e){
     if(event.touches.length == 1){
          //Handle one finger tap
     }
});
```

Otherwise, jGestures has "tapone", "taptwo", "tapthree" events to handle the taps.

```
element.on('tapone', function(e){
     //Handle one finger tap
});
```

More events are documented [here](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not working. Is there any other way?